# Audience control over conflict resolution

Tags: shock-social-science-fiction

In *Shock: Social Science Fiction*, in explaining the conflict mechanics, pages 34-35 state:

> If your *Tagonists are not involved in this Conflict,
>   you’re Audience in this scene. Roll 1d4 to use at your
>   discretion to effect the outcome of the Conflict with
>   Minutiæ. Every Audience member will be rolling one, but only the highest will count right now. (If more than one is the highest
>   and wants to do something, all those players should roll anther
>   die each. Whoever gets the highest number on that die gets to use
>   hir Minutia.) **Now tell how one of the Minutiæ in the middle of the
>   table** — either one that already exist or a new one you made up
>   on the spot — **changes the outcome of the Conflict.**

My understanding of this is that the Audience member who rolls highest gets to single-handedly determine the outcome. Isn't that a bit excessive? It sounds as though the entire conflict mechanics *between the two *Tagonists* get completely overridden by a simple 1d4 toss.

Is that the intention, or am I misreading this? Does this work better in real-play than it sounds on paper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highest-rolling Audience member doesn't automatically get to choose the outcome.

There are two sides of the Conflict, and it is possible for both *Tagonists to win or both to lose because their Intents are not mutually exclusive.  The Audience can choose to (but is not required to) affect one *Tagonist's result by adjusting the *Tagonist's d10 roll by adding or subtracting the Audience's d4 roll.  Affecting a *Tagonist's result also requires the Audience to narrate the complication with Minutiæ.  If one *Tagonist is winning by a large enough margin (or if the Audience rolls poorly), then they can't change the outcome except by the introduction of Minutiæ.

The intention is that the Audience has significant sway in one side of the Conflict.

This is slightly clarified on page 36 and in the Playing the Audience section on page 64.

> *Page 64*
>
> Your job as an Audience member is to **push things the way you want them to go**.